# XMLSerializer.serializeToString has a bug on process script tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

```
const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
const foreignObject = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
foreignObject.appendChild(document.createElement('script'))
svg.appendChild(foreignObject);
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg)
// "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><foreignObject><script xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"></script></foreignObject></svg>"
```

the code string `<script>` becomes to `\x3Cscript>` and `</script>`  becomes to `\x3C/script>` ，the result is not right how can i fix this?

and safari works just fine

[safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXyVU.png)

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIyg3.png)

[use createElemetNS for all elemtes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Ggy.png)

[this is strange in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoOGt.png)

[this is strange in chrome 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWL9P.png)

Comment: i edited this demo, and the result is the same when i use createElementNS

Comment: Can't reproduce, https://jsfiddle.net/r0uvd4x8/ logs `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><foreignObject><script xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></script></foreignObject></svg>` to console for me in a current Chrome.

Comment: @Egssy You forgot createElementNS for script too.

Comment: @RobertLongson see `use createElementNS for all elements` thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **do not have a problem**, this is just how Chrome is displaying the information to you.

---

Notice how, in your screenshot, the output is surrounded with `'` characters.

This is because Chrome is telling you that the value is a string by rendering it as a string literal.

Inside a string, `\x3C` means `<`.

The use of an escape character is so that it can be copy/pasted into an HTML `<script>` element without the sequence `</script>` inside the string literal prematurely triggering the end of the HTML script element.

---

You can get a more accurate view of what the output actually looks like by replacing the last line with:

```js
const src = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
const pre = document.createElement("pre");
pre.textContent = src;
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

Answer (score 0):

Output your constructed SVG

```js
const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
const foreignObject = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
foreignObject.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
svg.appendChild(foreignObject);
let output = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
document.body.innerHTML = output.replaceAll("<","&lt;");
```

```js
const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
const foreignObject = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
foreignObject.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
svg.appendChild(foreignObject);
let output = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
document.body.textContent = output;
```

Comment: Using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` + `replaceAll` is easier and will get *all* the special characters in the string, not just start-of-tag ones.